# Google BigQuery SQL Error - Syntax error: Expected ")" but got "(" at [4:12]

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This Google data analysis course is killing me. I keep getting errors that I can't seem to solve with the course info. Here is the code and the error.

```
WITH longest_used_bike AS (
    SELECT 
        bikeid
        SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration
    FROM 
        `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips`
    GROUP BY
        bikeid
    ORDER BY 
        trip_duration DESC 
    LIMIT 1
    )
## find the station at which longest bikeshare ride started
SELECT 
    trips.start_station_id,
    COUNT(*) AS trip_ct
FROM 
    longest_used_bike AS longest
INNER JOIN 
    `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips` AS trips
ON longest.bikeid = trips.bikeid
GROUP BY 
    trips.start_station_id
ORDER BY 
    trips_ct DESC
LIMIT 1
```

ERROR

```
Syntax error: Expected ")" but got "(" at [4:12]
```

Comment: You're missing a comma between `bikeid` and `SUM()`, you're also going to have an issue with your order by as you have the column as trips when the column is trip.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a comma after the data below:
SELECT
**bikeid,**
SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration

Answer (score 0):

This Google Data Analysis Course **is killing me, TOO!**

Here is the code and the solution:

```
WITH longest_used_bike AS (
    SELECT 
        bike_id,
        SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration
    FROM 
        `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips`
    GROUP BY
        bike_id
    ORDER BY 
        trip_duration DESC 
    LIMIT 1
    )
## find the station at which longest bikeshare ride started
SELECT 
    trips.start_station_id,
    COUNT(*) AS trip_ct
FROM 
    longest_used_bike AS longest
INNER JOIN 
    `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips` AS trips
ON longest.bike_id = trips.bike_id
GROUP BY 
    trips.start_station_id
ORDER BY 
    trip_ct DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: welcome and thank you for contributing a good answer. If you could add some explanation of what you fixed, that would be wonderful to future readers.